# Filtering SQL Server transactional replication

Tags: sql-server-2012, transactional-replication

I have a transactional replication publication which is filtered by rows.  When the subscription was initialized, Record A did not insert to the subscriber because it did not meet the filter condition of "Column X is null".  Some time later, Column X on Record A is updated so that Column X is now null.  Does the record now get inserted into the subscriber table or, since the transaction at the publisher was an Update, nothing at all gets applied at the subscriber and the record stays out of the subscriber?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I did decide to test it today after posting this.  In the example I provided SQL Server did appear to insert the record after the update was applied that caused it to meet the filter criteria.  Thinking of replication as merely duplicating a transaction I was skeptical.  I thought I could get a quick answer before testing it.